# Udev not running xinput command inside script

Tags: udev, xinput

I'm trying to make it so that when I connect an external mouse I can automatically remap the buttons. I can remap buttons manually with `xinput set-button-map $mouse_id $button_map`

However, I'm having trouble making this automatic. I'm currently trying to have udev run a a script whenever the device is connected. I have this rule as `/etc/udev/rules.d/my_rule.rules`:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="dummy", ATTRS{idProduct}=="dummy", RUN+="/bin/bash /path/to/my_script.sh"
```

and `my_script.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_file=/path/to/out.txt
mouse_id=dummy
button_map=dummy
# button map before
/usr/bin/xinput get-button-map $mouse_id >> $out_file
/usr/bin/xinput set-button-map $mouse_id $button_map
# button map after
/usr/bin/xinput get-button-map $mouse_id >> $out_file
```

The script runs exactly as expected if I call it from a terminal, but the issue is that in the udev bash environment xinput isn't running at all. None of the three calls to it do anything. Even something like `/usr/bin/xinput >> $out_file` does nothing. However, something like `echo foobar >> $out_file` does put output in the out file.

I've been looking at various stuff like this [writing udev rules guide](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) and I've changed all the various calls to absolute paths as some other posts suggested, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Trying to run that from an udev rule is broken in the first place.

Comment: @user414777 what do you mean broken?

Comment: It assumes that you're running a single display, by a single user, without restarting it; you're connecting to an insecure X11 display as root; etc, etc. Any X11 client application running as the logged in user can listen for xinput events, and act on them. Your DE may be already doing that. If it doesn't, try [`inputplug`](https://github.com/andrewshadura/inputplug) (it's a package, at least on Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept looking and found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/972964/access-xinput-from-acpi-bash-script-on-debian) on the superuser stackexchange that says that xinput needs to have the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environment variables set, I was able to modify my script and it worked! However, I also had to add a sleep and make it run in the background. Here's my final script:

`my_rule.rules`:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="dummy", ATTRS{idProduct}=="dummy", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/my_sript.sh"
```

`my_script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
out_file=/path/to/out.txt
# run normal if given argument, start new in background else
if [[ $1 ]]
then
    sleep 1
    mouse_id="my_mouse's_id"
    xenv="env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/my_name/.Xauthority"
    # button map before
    $xenv /usr/bin/xinput get-button-map "$mouse_id" >> $out_file
    $xenv /usr/bin/xinput set-button-map "$mouse_id" 2 3 2 4 5 6 7 1 9
    # button map after
    $xenv /usr/bin/xinput get-button-map "$mouse_id" >> $out_file
    echo finished >> $out_file
else
    echo running > $out_file
    # run it, but detached in the background
    /path/to/my_script.sh run_normal & 
fi
```

I also want to note for anyone else that udev calls the script like 18 times when I plug in the mouse, but it doesn't seem to be an issue.